# How to move the date text to the right end of the page in the resume?

Tags: cv

I want to move the dates of the internship to the right side of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{palatino}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\medskip
    \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth- 
2\fboxsep\relax}\small 
                    \textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}
                  \end{minipage}}
                        \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}
\begin{center} \textbf{TRIDEV} \end{center}
Roll No.: \textbf{2K20/AE/73} \\
Email-id : \textbf{tridev} \\
Mobile No.: \textbf{+91-} \\
\resheading{INTERNSHIPS}
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Role, Company} \textit{(Dates)}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Work description.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I searched on the net but everyone else used the `\section{}` method, I only want to use the `\resheading{}` method.

Comment: Please make a small, but compilable test document so people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hack: use something like `\hfill` before the date

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{palatino}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\medskip
    \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth- 
2\fboxsep\relax}\small 
                    \textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}
                  \end{minipage}}
                        \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}
\begin{center} \textbf{TRIDEV} \end{center}
Roll No.: \textbf{2K20/AE/73} \\
Email-id : \textbf{tridev} \\
Mobile No.: \textbf{+91-} \\
\resheading{INTERNSHIPS}
    \begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Role, Company} \hfill \textit{(Dates)}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Work description.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]